# Gatsby Time to Interactive (Lighthouse score) increased due to many imported (but unused) components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

**TLDR:** I'm developing a Gatsby site which is sourcing from a JSON API. The site has grown quite a bit and this has increased the Google Lighthouse TTI (Time to Interactive) to unacceptable levels (about 7 seconds). I think it's caused by having too many imported components which *usually* aren't even used..

**Detailed explanation:**

The architecture of the site is quite simple, each page has a list of modules. Example:

```
{ path: 'page-1', modules: ['a'] },
{ path: 'page-2', modules: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] },
{ path: 'page-3', modules: ['g', 'a'] }
```

The modules are unique components and can range between 10 to 200 lines of code. For example module `a` is a Content component and module `b` is an Image component.

A very basic code example of how the `Page` component renders the modules:

```
import React from 'react'
import Module from './module'

const Page = ({ page }) => (
  <>
    <h1>{page.title}</h1>
    {page.modules.map((module, index) => (
      <Module module={module} key={index} />
    ))}
  </>
)

export default Page
```

A code example of the `Module` component (in reality this component contains around 20(!) modules which all need an **import**)

```
import React from 'react'
import ModuleA from '../modules/module-a'
import ModuleB from '../modules/module-b'
import ModuleC from '../modules/module-c'

const Module = (props) => {
  const module = props.module
  switch (module) {
    case 'a':
      return <ModuleA {...module} />
    case 'b':
      return <ModuleB {...module} />
    case 'c':
      return <ModuleC {...module} />
    // etc...
    default:
      return <></>
  }
}

export default Module
```

**The problem:**
The TTI (Time to Interactive) value is 7 seconds for every page. This means that the TTI isn't  affected by the amount of modules a page has. It seems that all the imported components are added to the Gatsby build, even though they aren't actually used by a page.

**The question:**

- Is Gatsby or Webpack failing to filter (shake) out the unused (but imported) components?
- Is there a way to dynamically import components?

Example source code can be found here: https://github.com/joostelders/gatsby-example. Few important notes:

- The project uses Gatsby Themes, this means that component shadowing is a requirement.
- The TTI value isn't testable via the given repo, to really see this you need a big project with many components (I obviously cannot share this)